# How to start desktop for LINUX RHEL7.3 server

Tags: linux, desktop

I am given a server IP address in my working environment. The only current way to access it is to use PuTTY command line. The LINUX server has no internet access.

However, i would like to access the GUI of LINUX (desktop) for easier navigation and running of apps, is there any way to do it?

Comment: My only way to access RHEL is through PuTTY. I am using windows. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of assumptions here that you need to figure out.

1. A GUI on the RHEL server requires the server must have the necessary software installed, xorg-x11 at the least.

   - This assumes you have root/superuser access on this server. If you 
     do not have this access, you may not install additional software on it.
   - If you do have root privileges, and this server does not have internet access it will be very difficult because you will not be able to download the appropriate software packages.
2. You must have the necessary software on your Windows computer (the client) to connect to this GUI. [Cygwin X](http://x.cygwin.com/) is such a software package.

Assuming you **can** do this, search in your favorite Search Engine for "centos install x windows". Here is an [example result](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-a-gui-on-top-of-centos-7/).

PS - RHEL and Centos are very similar. But since more people use Centos you will find more/better search results using it.